# Android - Browser.BookmarkColumns cannot be resolved in Zxing Library

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I am developing app with zxing library. I imported the zxing project into my work place. While importing there is a problem that i have been facing. 
           Browser.BookmarkColumns cannot be resolved or is not a type.

Below is the code and screenshot provided. A small hint will be enough...

### BookmarkPickerActivity.java

```
public final class BookmarkPickerActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final String TAG = BookmarkPickerActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String[] BOOKMARK_PROJECTION = { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };

static final int TITLE_COLUMN = 0;
static final int URL_COLUMN = 1;

private static final String BOOKMARK_SELECTION = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 1 AND " + Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL + " IS NOT NULL";

private Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks, BOOKMARK_PROJECTION, BOOKMARK_SELECTION, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "No cursor returned for bookmark query");
        finish();
        return;
    }
    setListAdapter(new BookmarkAdapter(this, cursor));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (!cursor.isClosed() && cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        intent.putExtra(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, cursor.getString(TITLE_COLUMN));
        intent.putExtra(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL, cursor.getString(URL_COLUMN));
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    } else {
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    }
    finish();
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[Most things related to `Bookmarks` were removed in API Level 23](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser) (Android 6.0). You have your `compileSdkVersion` (a.k.a., build target in Eclipse) set to API Level 23. You can drop your `compileSdkVersion` to something lower to get past this error, but the code itself will not work on Android 6.0+.

Comment: When they say don't access bookmarks from the global provider or use the bookmark permissions. Instead, your app should store bookmarks data internally. what do they realy mean?

Comment: @PradeepSingh: They mean exactly what they say. Each Web browser app should be maintaining its own collection of bookmarks.

Comment: is there any Solution to this? or any other means of implementing qr-code in my app?

Comment: @PradeepSingh: Quoting myself in my answer: "You can drop your `compileSdkVersion` to something lower to get past this error, but the code itself will not work on Android 6.0+". You can either remove the bookmark support code entirely, or you can check the `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` at runtime and skip over the bookmark code on Android 6.0+ devices. Bear in mind that `zxing` is an app, not a library.

Answer (score 2):

**Option1:** Change compileSdkVersion 23 to 22 on build.gradle file to solve this issue..

**Option2:** Use **Reflection** method to get the Browser History in compileSdkVersion >=23.

Comment: How do I use the reflection method? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new version of [Zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/share/BookmarkPickerActivity.java), that was updated to api **25**